# How to add invalid records to has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

I have a house model with a has_many-association for rooms.

```
house = House.find 1
dining_room = Room.find 1
living_room = Room.find 2
```

The living_room is not a valid dataset. So if I add the rooms to the house

```
house << dining_room
house << living_room
```

the living_room wasn't added, because it's invalid.

How can I skip the validation when adding an existing record to a has_many-association?

Comment: How did either room get saved if they're invalid?

Comment: `living_room = Room.find 2` ? this is a valid entry on your rooms table ?

Comment: @j-dexx  i added the validation after the data were inserted

Comment: @sa77 No, the entry for id 2 is not valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like this to associate a `Room` object to a `House` object skipping validation:

declare something like this in `room.rb`

```
def associate_room_to_house!(house)
  self.house_id = house.id
  self.save(:validate => false)
end
```

and then use this method on your invalid room object.

```
house = House.find 1
living_room = Room.find 2

living_room.associate_room_to_house!(house)
```

Answer (score 1):

If a living_room belongs to a house you can simply update the `house_id` on that living room record to match the house you'd like it to belong to.